# How to import MongoDb collection data to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mysql-workbench

I want to import data from MongoDb to MySQL. For that i have exported the MongoDb collection as json and imported the same in MySQL. But when i did that the data have not imported properly. Is there any other method to do that? Here is the snap [image: ngo]attached

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  MongoDB API-> Export the data: mongoexport --db test --collection traffic --out traffic.json
Step 2: SQLizer API-> 
    Initiate the file conversion
    Upload your file
    Monitor the conversion progress
    Download your converted file
Step 3:SQL file into SQL database -> Now all that’s left to do is truely import/upload your new SQL document into your database. Because SQLizer has pre-defined TABLE and INSERT statements this step is actually waiting for your report to import/add.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In articles i have read that MySQL 8 also supports NoSQL. How to enable that and can we not not directly import json(from step-1) to MySQL NoSQL.